# Вывод дня недели по дате Y-m-d H:i:s

Tags: php, дата

Доброго времени!

такая проблема, хочу получить номер дня недели по дате, но у меня почему то постоянно выдает 4 - какую бы дату не ставил, вот скрипт

```
 echo date("w",'2016-03-11 15:02:00')."<br>";
 echo date("w",'2016-03-12 15:02:00')."<br>";
 echo date("w",'2016-03-13 15:02:00')."<br>";
```

выдает 4 4 4, может я не правильно понял как работает функция даты? почему мне постоянно выдает 4й день?

Comment: У вас второй параметр не формата timestamp, а строка. Используйте так - date('w', strtotime('2016-03-11 15:00:03')).   (http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov можно не стесняться и написать это как ответ. Ну или найти дубликат, если такой вопрос уже был

Comment: @Ипатьев да, согласен, немного отступил от привычки давать наводящие, а не полные ответы :)